# Why does this scp copy from Windows fail when copying the containing folder, but not when coping the individual contents?

Tags: windows, scp

I'm using `scp` to copy a folder from Windows 10 back to Ubuntu 20.4 (all software has been updated).

```
$ uname -a
Linux ray-desktop 5.15.0-46-generic #49~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 4 19:15:44 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

This is what's on the Windows 10 host:

```
$ ssh asus -n 'dir Desktop\Test\_Underscore\_Albert\2022'
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is 545E-5BEF

 Directory of C:\Users\ray\Desktop\Test\_Underscore\_Albert\2022

2023-01-22  04:35 PM    <DIR>          .
2023-01-22  04:35 PM    <DIR>          ..
2023-01-22  04:35 PM    <DIR>          Receipts
2023-01-22  04:35 PM    <DIR>          Signed
2023-01-22  04:35 PM    <DIR>          WorkProduct
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               5 Dir(s)  681,766,621,184 bytes free
```

This copies the "2022" folder correctly:

```
$ scp -q -r -p asus:Desktop/Test/_Underscore/_Albert copy-underscore-albert

$ ls copy-underscore-albert/2022
Receipts  Signed  WorkProduct
```

This copies the folder that contains the "2022" folder, but fails:

```
$ scp -q -r -p asus:Desktop/Test/_Underscore copy-underscore
[exit status 1]

$ ls copy-underscore/_Albert/2022
Receipts
```

The "Receipts" folder is copied completely.
The other two folders are missing.

The same thing happens if I copy the "Test" folder.

Trying again, verbosely:

```
$ scp -v -r -p asus:Desktop/Test/_Underscore copy-underscore >&copy.out
[exit status 1]

$ tail -20 copy.out
Sink: T1643869420 0 1674423352 0
Sending file modes: C0666 4528 model.cdat
Sink: C0666 4528 model.cdat
File mtime 1674423352 atime 1674666044
Sending file timestamps: T1674423352 0 1674666044 0
Sink: T1674423352 0 1674666044 0
Entering directory: D0777 0 Temp
Sink: D0777 0 Temp
File mtime 1674423353 atime 1674666044
Sending file timestamps: T1674423353 0 1674666044 0
Sink: T1674423353 0 1674666044 0
ESink: D0777 0 2
ntering directory: D0777 0 2
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: fd 2 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Transferred: sent 54028, received 163861768 bytes, in 9.7 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 5549.1, received 16829918.5
debug1: Exit status -1073741571
```

This is consistently repeatable.

Any idea what is going wrong here?

Comment: Is the "normal" message output (without either `-v` **or** `-q`) any more enlightening?

Comment: @steeldriver, no, it doesn't say anything, but still exit(1).